# How to remove graph showing in the range slider?

Tags: shiny, plotly

I am developing a R Shiny dashboard and making use of the range slider, however I do not like the repeat of the chart showing in the slider - how do I remove this?

I have just sent the link from the plotly info page to show what I mean:

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPRpK.png)

I have created this:

xaxis_plots[["rangeslider"]] <- list(range="week_ending", visible = TRUE, thickness = 0.05, bgcolor = "#ECEBF3")

However, it still shows the chart inside when I add it to plotly code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way. We plot two times the series. One invisibly and we add the range slider for this series. Then we plot the second series on a second x-axis.

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(x = time(USAccDeaths), y = USAccDeaths, xaxis = "x2") %>%
  add_lines(x = time(USAccDeaths), y = USAccDeaths, visible = FALSE) %>%
  layout(
      xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(visible = TRUE)),
      xaxis2 = list(matches = "x", overlaying = "x")
  )
```

[image]